# What is the strategy for Google AdSense to open ads link?

Tags: google-adsense

People were talking about Google AdSense force the visitor to open the ad window in the same page. But I found that my ads are mostly open in new page. But still some are opened in the same page.

What is the detailed rule about this? Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Google, they open ads in a new window based on the user's location. In some countries/cultures, it is the prevailing norm for links to open in a new window.

> Generally, it is our policy to not allow Google ads to open in a new window. However, in a few markets, including China, we've found that opening ads in a new window better aligns with expected internet behavior and provides a more consistent, intuitive user experience.
>
> Keeping in mind the importance of the user experience, we've enabled Google ads to open in new windows in locations where this is expected browsing behavior. This functionality is determined by the IP of the user, and is not an option you can select your AdSense account.

([Source](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en))